# Membership handling for separate Web API backend and AngularJS front-end

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I've a MS ASP.NET Web API 2 backend serving JSON for consuming by a very separate AngularJS-based front-end. I need membership handling (authentication/authorisation) preferably with JWT (Jason Web Token). I'm familiar with MS simple membership and Identity 2.1 to some extent but I'm struggling to interface with that from the AngularJS-based UI.

Identity 2 gives me all the functionality I need and I'd rather avoid using ASP.NET MVC - the Web API I use fronts a SQL database and the rest is AngularJS driven.

Comment: You can read the whole series in this [blog](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/).You will find a few detailed articles where the author will guide you through the steps needed to build what you're trying to do.